TypeError: _contex_provider__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.useCartContext() is undefined
estoy haciendo un Sistema de tienda con React js en el que estoy usando un useContext, todo bien pero me aparece TypeError: contex_provider__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1_.useCartContext() is undefined.
Mi componente provider.js:
import React, { useState, useContext, createContext } from 'react';

export const useCartContext = () => useContext(AppContext);

const Provider = ({ children }) => {
    const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

    return (
        <AppContext.Provider value={{ user, setUser }}>
            {children}
        </AppContext.Provider>
    );
};

const AppContext = createContext();

export default Provider 



y este es mi componente navBar:
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import { useCartContext } from './contex/provider'

const NavBar = () => {
  const {user} = useCartContext()
  const refreshPage =()=> {
        window.location.reload(false);
}
  
  return (
    <div>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li onClick={refreshPage}><Link to='/' >Empleados</Link></li>
                <li><Link to='/registroDeEmpleado'>Registro De Empleado</Link></li>
                
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
  )
}

export default NavBar

Saben por que me aparece ese error?

Verifica si Provider esta envolviendo a la app
